# N-Divisible Digits small program

Tags: c++

Heres the idea
Write a program that takes two integers, N and M, and find the largest integer composed of N-digits that is evenly divisible by M. N will always be 1 or greater, with M being 2 or greater. Note that some combinations of N and M will not have a solution.
Example: if you are given an N of 3 and M of 2, the largest integer with 3-digits is 999, but the largest 3-digit number that is evenly divisible by 2 is 998, since 998 Modulo 2 is 0. Another example is where N is 2 and M is 101. Since the largest 2-digit integer is 99, and no integers between 1 and 99 are divisible by 101, there is no solution.

I would just like some tips on what to improve

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>

using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::runtime_error; 
using std::pow;

unsigned largestNumber(unsigned num1) {
return pow(10, num1) - 1;
}

void validNums(const int num1, const int num2) {
    if (num1 < 1 || num1 > 9 || num2 < 2 || num2 > 999999999)
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid input");
}

int divisbleBy(int num1, int num2) {
    for (; num1 != 0; --num1) {
        if (num1 % num2 == 0)
            return num1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    cout << "Enter 2 nums and we'll find biggest number possible with num1 digits and we'll then find closest number that num2 can divide by. Num1 has to be between 1-9 and num2 between 2-999-999-999" << endl;
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    validNums(num1, num2);
    if (answer = divisbleBy(largestNumber(num1), num2))
        cout << "Largest number possible with " << num1 << " is " << largestNumber(num1) << " and the closest number to " << largestNumber(num1) << " divisible by " << num2 << " is " << answer << endl;
    else
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to find the `O(1)` algorithm for this problem, instead of using your current `O(M)` algorithm.

For example, given the input `9 500000001`, your program takes 2.3 seconds (on my laptop) to run through the half-billion integers between 999999999 and 500000001. Whereas, using the relatively obvious O(1) algorithm, it takes 0.007 seconds.

Since this looks like homework and/or a Project Euler–type problem, I won't give the spoiler here.

---

Stylistically,

- Prefer to write out `std::cin`, `std::cout`, etc., instead of wasting space at the top of the program with a bunch of `using` directives. It's shorter, cleaner, and (most importantly) more idiomatic to qualify names at the point of use instead of relying on `using` directives to pull them into scope.
- Your function `validNums` [uses exceptions for control flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107723/arguments-for-or-against-using-try-catch-as-logical-operators), which is frowned upon in C++. Prefer to make it a function returning `bool`, and have its caller do something sensible (such as print an error message) if the given numbers aren't valid.
- You have a named abstraction for `largestNumber`, when that could just as well have been a named local variable `int largestNumber = pow(...);`.
- You *don't* have a named abstraction for `produceTheActualAnswer`; instead, you inline a complicated test `if (answer = divisbleBy(largestNumber(num1), num2))` straight into `main`. This makes it unnecessarily difficult to switch out your bad old algorithm for a new and better one.
- Putting an assignment inside an `if` condition is supremely bad style — so bad that both GCC and Clang (and probably MSVC too) will emit a warning on this code. You should write either

  ```
  int answer = produceTheActualAnswer(num1, num2);
  if (answer != 0) {
      ...
  } else {
      ...
  }
  ```

  or, if you really want to use "interesting" features of C++, you might write

  ```
  if (int answer = produceTheActualAnswer(num1, num2)) {
      ...
  } else {
      ...
  }
  ```

  But I don't recommend the latter.

---

You should also consider taking your `num1` and `num2` parameters via the command line, instead of reading them from stdin:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        // maybe read them from stdin anyway
    } else {
        int m = std::atoi(argv[1]);
        int n = std::atoi(argv[2]);
        int answer = f(m, n);
        if (answer != 0) { ... } else { ... }
    }
}
```

This makes it easier to test your code quickly from the command line, and also makes it easy to `time ./a.out 9 500000001` to see if you've beaten my 0.007 seconds yet. ;)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answers :) Why is declaration in if bad? I fixed up my code just not that 0(1) thing can you explain it? Btw this isn't homwork I just found it off /r/dailyprogrammer :) Heres my code http://pastebin.com/yfBg1yPW

Comment: You didn't change very much in that pastebin — all the logic is still stacked up in `main` instead of being factored out into a function (`produceTheActualAnswer` was my slightly humorous suggestion for that function's name). I don't recommend `if (int answer = ...)` because it's an arcane feature of the language, so it would confuse people. Plus, once you slip into that habit, it's just a matter of time before you write `if (auto it = map.find(key)) { ... *it ... }` and ta-da, you've written a bug. Better to just not tempt fate at all.

Comment: Here I put the logic in a function and if it returns non zero its good if its 0 its bad http://pastebin.com/6zaCT3D0 also can you tell me what that 0(1) this was I have algorithms in the next chapter so it should cover it :)

Comment: Or should I make it so it just returns the answer and doesn't change num1 so I could call it multiple times but then I couldn't get the largest num.

Comment: Well, here's a hint: Given some integer `x`, how would you (in a single arithmetic expression) find the largest number less than or equal to `x` that is divisible by 2? divisible by 4? divisible by 10? divisible by `m`? And then, having done that, how would you check whether that number had exactly `n` digits or fewer than `n` digits?

Comment: here http://pastebin.com/zizhAK0W I got some help from reddit :) Is my code logic/design good tho?

Comment: You've still got an unnecessary loop in there, and the function's name is both wrong and misspelled. But yeah, Reddit figured out the obvious algorithm. :)

Comment: Ya I fixed the loop after I posted it thanks for the help and all tho :)

Answer (score 0):

#### User interface improvement

Tell the requirements as near to their need as possible, your interface is:

```
Enter 2 nums and we'll find biggest number possible with num1 digits and we'll then 
find closest number that num2 can divide by.
Num1 has to be between 1-9 and num2 between 2-999-999-999
```

The user then has to enter the two numbers with no prompt at all.

I would prefer this interface:

```
Enter 2 nums and we'll find biggest number possible with num1 
digits and we'll then find closest number that num2 can divide by.
The first number? [From 1 to 9] 5
The second number? [From 2 to 999_999_999] 412
```

This way the probability of error drops as the user gets the constraints one by one just before entering the numbers.

Even better would be to avoid vague names like `num1` and `num2` or `first number` and `second number` and give the user a more precise prompt:

```
Given a number of digits `d` and a number `n`
This program will find the biggest number with `d` digits divisible by `n` 
How many digits? [From 1 to 9] 8
Divisible by? [From 2 to 999_999_999] 213414
```

This final version is way more clear and user friendly than the first prompt, that was pretty vague.

And while I am at it, I would also clean up the output to avoid the `9999...` triviality and give just the information asked for in a more precise format:

```
The biggest number with 7 digits divisible by 999 is: 9999990
```